# Bootstrap Custom CSS won't override Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

What I am trying to achieve is that I've got a custom file that is supposed to override the default bootstrap css. ( It is supposed to change the navbar menu color, navbar background etc ).

P.S. I am using **EJS** with **Node 5.7.1**.

Nevertheless, I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Strawberio</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/b/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/c/g.controller.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/a/layout/style.css"
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Strawberio</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-app="stack">
   <%- body %>
  </div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

But if you look at this specific line:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/a/layout/style.css"
```

The Link tag does not end... however... it works.

If I do close the link tag as following:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/a/layout/style.css">
```

The custom file does not override the default bootstrap. It loads it but it does not override.

Do you have any idea why?

Thank you,
Alexandru S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<nav>` tag is improperly nested in your HTML `<head>` tag. Move the `nav` to inside the `<body>`. The `<head>` should only contain `<title>`, `<style>`, `<meta>`, `<link>`, `<script>`, and `<base>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors open a closing the head a body tags. You should always put your content inside body tag not in the head tag!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Strawberio</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/b/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/c/g.controller.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/a/layout/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Strawberio</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <div ng-app="stack">
    <%- body %>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah that was caused by my ejs being wronged configured, thank you for the response, Andre.